# Can't from source install torchvision0.4.0 on jetson nano with jetpack4.2.2

Tags: python-3.x, torchvision, nvidia-jetson-nano

**jetson nano**

```
ubantu18.04
```

**jetpack version:4.2.2**

**python version:3.6.9**

**cuda version:10.0**

`pytorch:1.2.0`(install from wheel v1.2.0&jetpack4.2.2&python3.6:https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-11-now-available/72048)

`pytorch` can normally import, than I run:

```
$git clone --branch v0.4.0 https://github.com/pytorch/vision torchvision 
$cd torchvision
$python setup.py install
```

after building, I try to import `torchvision`, but:error:"SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined"

than I go to see source code, but in `setup.py` line32 is "version = '0.4.1a0'"
than I try to reset to last commit which `setup.py` line32 is "version = '0.4.0a0'"

after that, I delete the build folder and rerun $python `setup.py` install

than I retry import but sim error:

```
">>> import torchvision

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "/home/ucar/ucar_ws2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision-0.4.0a0+ef3ba78-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg/torchvision/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "/home/ucar/ucar_ws2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision-0.4.0a0+ef3ba78-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "/home/ucar/ucar_ws2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision-0.4.0a0+ef3ba78-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg/torchvision/datasets/lsun.py", line 2, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "/home/ucar/ucar_ws2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Pillow-9.2.0-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 52, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 894, in _find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1157, in find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1131, in _get_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1112, in _legacy_get_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 441, in spec_from_loader

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 544, in spec_from_file_location

File "/home/ucar/ucar_ws2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Pillow-9.2.0-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg/PIL/_deprecate.py", line 1

SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined"
```

I'm so sad about it, could you help me, thank you first!!!

Comment: The annotations future is only available starting with python 3.7, see [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7). It looks like you are running python 3.6 judging from `Pillow-9.2.0-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg`. Have you tried with other python versions?

Comment: @FlyingTeller : I downloaded all packages with python3.6 as version, I don't understand why to change python version